# VS Code: Is it possible to theme the selected folder in explorer view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While using VS Code in larger projects, I have trouble seeing which file and folder I have open.

My current explorer looks like this:

[image: Current VS Code explorer view]

I can see a selected folder, but that quickly becomes difficult to see when I am in a project with hundreds of folders and/or files.

I'd like the selected folder to look like this. *(Purely to illustrate this I've selected all the files in the current folder)*

[image: Mock VS Code explorer view]

But with the open file highlighted somehow.

Is it possible to theme the explorer view in this way?

Comment: look in the themable color list if such a color name exists